# Spring Internalization to print country in the right language

Tags: java, spring

When I want to access at the page with address?language=en or language=fr, I use the following controller :

```
public class AddressController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddressController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView init(HttpServletRequest r){
            ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml");
            SessionLocaleResolver resolver = (SessionLocaleResolver) context.getBean("localeResolver");

            String[] locales = resolver.resolveLocale(r).getISOCountries();
            //String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
            Map<String,String> countryList = new HashMap<String,String>();

            for(String countryCode : locales){
                 Locale loc = new Locale(resolver.resolveLocale(r).getLanguage(),countryCode);
                 countryList.put(loc.getDisplayCountry(), loc.getDisplayCountry());
                 logger.info(loc.getDisplayCountry());
             }

             Map<String,String> tree = new TreeMap<String,String>(countryList);
             ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("address");
             modelAndView.addObject("address",new Address());
             modelAndView.addObject("countriesList", tree);

             return modelAndView;
     }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller" />
    <!-- <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->

    <!-- Register the messageBundle.properties -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
       <property value="classpath:MessageBundle,classpath:Messages" name="basenames" />
       <property value="UTF-8" name="defaultEncoding" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
          <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
         <property name="interceptors">
               <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
         </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" name="viewClass" />
         <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
         </property>
         <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
         </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I access to the controller by calling /address?language=en or /address?language=fr, I notice with the Logger in the loop 'for(String countryCode : locales)' that every country names print in french and not in english.

Do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the request parameter 'language' to create the the countries list? The SessionLocaleProvider will always return the same language as long as the session stays alive.

The following code sample takes the parameter to construct a list of localized country names:

```
@Controller
public class CountriesController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/countries", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getCountries(@RequestParam("language") String language){

        List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        String[] isoCountries = Locale.getISOCountries();
        for (String isoCountry : isoCountries) {

            Locale countryLoc = new Locale(language, isoCountry);
            String name = countryLoc.getDisplayCountry(locale);

            if (!"".equals(name)) {
               countries.add(name);
            }

         }

         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("countries");
         model.addObject("model", countries);

        return model;
   }
}
```